# How to verify String using JWSVerifier

Tags: jwt, jwk

New to `JWT`
I want to verify my string token which is generated as below

`String productkey`:which is signed and encoded format.

`String publickey`:Generated key from simmulator and store as string

```
JWSVerifier verifier= new ECSDVerifier(ECKey.parse(publickey))

Boolean test=verifier.verify(productkey);
```

Please suggest which appropriate method I have to used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to JWT, I would suggest you to use  **JJwt API**. You can easily sign your tokens and verify them.

Snippet to generate JWT token:

```
Jwts.builder()
        .setClaims(payload)
        .setExpiration(expiryDate)
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey )
        .compact();
```

Snippet to verify the token with public key:

```
Jwts.parser() 
   .setSigningKey(publicKey )
   .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken)
```

[JJwt Maven/Gradle link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.6.0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: But I have signed key using JWSSigner signer = new ECDSASigner(ECKey.parese(secretKey))  and signed jwsObject.sign(signer)         and JWS Object is like new JWSObject(new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.ES256).keyID("123").build),new Payload(pak));

Comment: Have you gone though this? Please take a look at example 13 and 14, that might help. If not, let me know some more details so that I can help better. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner